# Hold down tab in Applescript

Tags: google-chrome, applescript

I want to hold down tab and hit enter while in chrome.  I need an Applscript to automate it.  I have tried:

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke return while tab down
```

and

```
key down tab
tell application "System Events" to keystroke return
key up tab
```

and

```
key down (key code 48)
tell application "System Events" to keystroke return
key up (key code 48)
```

None of them will run because it gives a syntax error: "Expected end of line, etc. but found application constant or consideration."

I think the problem is that "tab" isn't a key that's meant to be help down.  The above would surely work for command, option, or control.  I haven't tried other keys to see which would work and which would not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible with vanilla AppleScript; key up/down affects only the modifier keys command, option, control and shift

Comment: Any documentation to back up the claim?  Also, is there an AppleScript superset language which can give me the desired results?

Comment: The key up/ key down command is not listed in the dictionary of System Events but it truly works only with the standard modifier keys. Maybe AppleScriptObjC could do the job which gives access to the Cocoa frameworks